# get_or_create and update_or_create save values more then once when executes at same time

Tags: python-3.5, django-celery, django-2.2

get_or_create and update_or_create save values more then once
when executes at same time

I am using djagno2.2 and python3.5

My code is something like this

```
class MyClass():

  def func1(arg = None):
    .......very large block of code.........
    This code can take 2-5 minutes to executes.
    .........
    MyModel.objects.get_or_create(name="abcd",defaults={Some params})   
    MyModel1.objects.update_or_create(name="abcd",defaults={Some params})
```

I used django-celery for background async processes and here is my *tasks.py* file

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

    from celery.decorators import periodic_task
    from celery.schedules import crontab


    @periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=00, hour=00))
    def every_day_midnight():
        """Executes every day at 00:00 am."""

        MyClass().func1()


    @periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/2'))
    def every_two_minutes():
        """Executes every 2 minutes"""

        MyClass().func1(arg)
```

Here i called MyClass().func1() daily midnight and same function executes with argument(arg) in every two minutes.

Now my problem is, This both functions are executes same time at midnight, so sometimes 
*MyModel and myModel1 saves duplicate values.* while i have used get_or_create and update_or_create

```
   MyModel.objects.get_or_create(name="abcd",defaults={Some params})   

   MyModel1.objects.update_or_create(name="abcd",defaults={Some params})
```

This problems occures due to both celery processes (every_day_midnight(),every_two_minutes())
executes at same time.

I have tried with transaction.automic but it didn't help me.

I want, When a process executes *MyClass()* or *MyClass().func1* other process should be wait to complete that process. Other ideas/solutions also welcome

How can i do this.
*Thanks in advance*